# Using threeparttable with mn2e class

Tags: article, threeparttable

I would like to use the `threeparttable` package to include table footnotes in an article that uses the [mn2e](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mnras/mn2e.cls) class. I have used this code from the `threeparttable` documentation:

```
\documentclass{mn2e}

\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
    \caption{...}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    42\tnote{1}& \\
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item [1] the first note
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I get the error message below because abovecaptionskip is not defined

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\Hy@tempa ...l \TPT@gatherlabel \abovecaptionskip 
                                                  \z@skip \else \TPT@docapt ...
```

Is it possible to use the `threeparttable` package with mn2e class?

Comment: You should provide a MWE for this.

Comment: I have added the preamble

Comment: You could add the missing length

Comment: Is there a documentation of this class. Obviously the author(s) do not want to have captions above tables?

Comment: The documentation is at http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mnras/mn2eguide.pdf (captions are above table)

Comment: Thanks for providing the documentation. The failure is an unhealthy mixture of `mn2e` and `threeparttable`. One should write a note to each of the authors/maintainers about the feature here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the missing length helps. I used the standard value from `scrbook` class. (it uses the value `10\p@`, so `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair is needed). It could be changed to any other length of course.

Obviously the class `mn2e` does not provide this length.

```
\documentclass{mn2e}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\abovecaptionskip}%
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{10\p@}
\makeatother
\usepackage{threeparttable}%

%\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\caption{...}
\begin{tabular}{cc}%
42\tnote{1}& \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [1] the first note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}%
```

### some explanation

From `threeparttable.sty`:

> % Note that the \caption formatting is *not* adjusted by
>   threeparttable. % You should use one of the caption-control packages
>   to get captions % that work well as table titles.  In truth,
>   threeparttable sets % \abovecaptionskip to zero for captions above the
>   table, but more % complete changes are called for.

The package does set `\abovecaptionskip` to zero, but obviously does not test if this length is defined at all. So, it is a double failure... `mn2e` does not define the length and `threeparttable` ungraciously assume, it's available.