# Single spacing within tables in a custom Class

Tags: tables, floats, line-spacing, document-classes

What is the simplest way to get single spacing in tables (both content and captions) and in figure caption, when the class is not using `setspace`? The class can be obtained [here](https://github.com/danielgallagher/UCF-Thesis-LaTeX-Template). When I use it as is with figure or tables, all table content and captions are double spaced. I tried loading `setspace` and using the tricks [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15442/why-does-doublespacing-using-setspace-have-errors-when-used-in-a-minimal-documen) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198065/using-threeparttable-with-mn2e-class) but in those cases, I get multitude of other errors.

I looked at `setspace` code but I don't really understand it that much. Is there any reasonable way to correct for this with this class or I should rather use `report` and try to change it according to the requirements (which i don't even know if I can do) because `setspace` and `report` work together. Also note, most of the tables that i use are `threeparttables` from `threepartablex` package, since I am using `longtable` inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document class, [ucfthes.cls](https://github.com/danielgallagher/UCF-Thesis-LaTeX-Template/blob/master/ucfthes.cls), modifies the low-level parameter `\baselinestretch` directly. (The `setspace` package is much more subtle in its ways.)

I suggest you issue the following directives in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}}
\AtEndEnvironment{table}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}}
\AtEndEnvironment{figure}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}}
```

This will automate switching back and forth between values of `\baselinestretch`.

Comment: Is the way the class does double spacing a good (or proper) one or is that an ugly way? Also, if I need a table to have a little spacing between rows, will `\def\arraystretch{1.1}` before `tabular` still work in the case of this class and your solution?

Comment: @leosenko - The method employed by the class -- direct manipulation of the low-level parameter `\baselinestretch` -- is indeed not felicitous. An immediate consequence of their poor choice is that double-spacing is applied *everywhere*, including in footnotes, tables, and figures. (The class code actually contains quite a few instructions to undo the effect for footnotes.) The `setspace` package uses a different method; an immediate benefit is that it does *not* affect footnotes, tables, and figures. Increasing the value of `\arraystretch` is a separate matter from `\baselinestretch`.